# How can I query with this model with sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I want to get applicants with each recruit steps connected with applicant.
But, It doesn't work well.

My Model Code

```
// Model

class Applicant extends Sequelze.Model{}
Applicant.init({
  // skip
});

class RecruitStep extends Sequelze.Model{}
RecruitStep.init({
  // skip
});

RecruitStep.belongsTo(Applicant, { as: 'applicant' }); // To Create applicantId (Foreign Key)
```

My Sequelize Query

```
const result = await Applicant.findAll({
  include: [
    { model: RecruitStep }
  ]
});
```

I think applicant don't know about recruit step and how can I query in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have the association from `RecruitStep` to `Applicant`. You need to do also the association the other way around, from `Applicant` to `RecruitStep` with `hasMany` or `hasOne` depending your schema.

```
Applicant.hasMany(RecruitStep, { as: 'steps' });
```

Then  on your query you add it like this:

```
const result = await Applicant.findAll({
  include: [
    { model: RecruitStep, as: 'steps' }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I Changed my assoiciation
RecruitStep.belongsTo -> Applicant.hasMany